# The research assistant badge?

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki

How does the computation of the badge [Research Assistant](https://ux.stackexchange.com/badges/80/research-assistant) work? Is the count 1:1 on each tag or is the Excerpt section separate giving the total of 2 if you edit both content and excerpt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **Research Assistant** tag is only related to the body text, not the excerpt.

This is a [link to the Stack Overflow Meta post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis/121484#121484) when this badge was introduced that gives you more information.

There is [another post on MSO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121517/research-assistant-badge-requirements) about this too.

Comment: Thanx, now I know (and thanx for the edit of the badge name!)